# Git command line: utility to copy long paths

Tags: command-line, git, clipboard

I'm using git command line client to do all my work. It works fine but I'm tired with copying long file paths e.g. with `git add long_path` or git `checkout long_branch_name` commands. Is there any helper application that would allow me to just choose files to do the operations e.g. copy them to clipboard or make some operations on these files so I don't have to use mouse every time to copy and paste.

Comment: Why not just use wildcards? Example filepath name `my/super/long/file/path/name/for/something/filename.ts` can be done with `git add */filename.ts`

Comment: Personally, I would avoid the whole thing with symlinks and or configuring my source to not contain stupid long paths.  To me (been a dev for 30 years), this is a sign of bad configuration management.  Also, you could create an alias and not need to use the command every time.